# Why transition doesn't work for border property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to remove `border` property after a wile *(1sec in here)*. Also I want to it remove smoothly. Here is my try:

```js
var elem = $('div').css({'border-top':'6px solid #FC9A24',
                'border-left':'1px dashed #FC9A24',
                'margin-top':'-6px'});
setTimeout(function() { elem.css({"transition":"border-color .5s ease"});}, 1000);
```

```css
div{
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Text</div>
```

But as you see, `border` doesn't remove. How can I fix it?

**Note:** similar code for `background-color` works as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transition goes in parallel with the css attributes, you can't just do transition by itself. Here's the way you can get it done.

```
var elem = $('div').css({'border-top':'12px solid green',
                          'border-left':'12px solid blue'});

$('button').click(function() {

setTimeout(function() 
           { 

              elem.css({'border-top':'0px solid green',
                      'border-left':'0px solid blue','transition':'border-top 5s ease, border-top 2s ease'});
           }, 1000);
     });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0bm4wq7h/16/

Comment: Emm, I don't know you understood what I want or not. But actually your fiddle is not really look like my point. Please give me a fiddle of a div which has a border, and its border get remove after 1sec.

Comment: Ok, tnx....! +1 -- However I wanted to set a `border` and remove it after a while (smoothly) at the same time.

Comment: just move the var elem inside the button click event . http://jsfiddle.net/0bm4wq7h/17/

Answer (score 1):

```js
setTimeout(function(){
    var elem = document.querySelector('p');
    elem.setAttribute('class','styled');
},1000);
```

```css
p {
    border: 2px solid #f00;
    transition: all ease-in-out 1s;
    -moz-transition: all ease-in-out 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 1s;
}
.styled {
    border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
```

Maybe something like this?:)
Adding class is much easier.
Cheers.

Comment: Well, as I said, I want to remove the border property, Not just change its color.

Comment: It's simple :). Just reverse process:
elem.style.border = '2px solid transparent';

Comment: Ok well, tnx for your answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

That's because `border-style` is non-animatable. You can only animate `border-color` and `border-width`.

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  document.querySelector('p').className = 'no-border';
}, 1e3);
```

```css
p {
  border: 25px solid #f00;
  transition: border-width linear 1s;
}
.no-border {
  border-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
```

Comment: Thanks. Sounds good. +1. Also I have a new/similar problem. Please take a loot at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/0bm4wq7h/20/). I want to when border shows and hides, div be in constant position. In other word, I want fix-position for div ever. How can I do that? *(as you see in fiddle, I added some margin for doing that, but it doesn't work correctly)*, Have you any idea?

Comment: @Shafizadeh You should animate margin too: http://jsfiddle.net/0bm4wq7h/21/. However, it may still not be pixel perfect and bounce a little. Better use an absolute element with `bottom: 100%` instead of the border, and animate its height.